# How to check for hold click Android studio/java

Tags: java, android, button

I want to make in my app when I hold click it does something and when I release the button it does something else. A variable will change to true when I hold and false when I release. How do I do that
(Android Studio)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use TouchListener and MotionEvent class. The MotionEvent class has Fields ACTION_UP, ACTION_DOWN, and ACTION_MOVE. You can use the getAction() method of the MotionEvent class.
Something like this

```
         findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // button pressed

        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           // button relased.

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onTouchListener` for your use case:

```
boolean isClicking = false;
myView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // the view is pressed
            isClicking = true;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           // the view is released.
           isClicking = true; 

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```